# Plot mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have several values of a function at different x points. I want to plot the mean and std in python, like the answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797846/plot-mean-standard-deviation-standard-error-of-the-mean-and-confidence-interv). I know this must be easy using matplotlib, but I have no idea of the function's name that can do that. Does anyone know it?

[image]

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html <- a good place to start to sort out what functions do what.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

[`plt.errorbar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar) can be used to plot x, y, error data (as opposed to the usual `plt.plot`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.power(x, 2) # Effectively y = x**2
e = np.array([1.5, 2.6, 3.7, 4.6, 5.5])

plt.errorbar(x, y, e, linestyle='None', marker='^')

plt.show()
```

`plt.errorbar` accepts the same arguments as `plt.plot` with additional `yerr` and `xerr` which default to None (i.e. if you leave them blank it will act as `plt.plot`).

[image: Example plot]

Comment: To add those small horizontal lines on the top and the bottom of a candle, specify the capsize option. E.g. to plt.errorbar(x, y, e, linestyle='None', marker='^', capsize=3)

Answer (score 20):

You may find an answer with this example : [errorbar_demo_features.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/errorbar_demo_features.html)

```
"""
Demo of errorbar function with different ways of specifying error bars.

Errors can be specified as a constant value (as shown in `errorbar_demo.py`),
or as demonstrated in this example, they can be specified by an N x 1 or 2 x N,
where N is the number of data points.

N x 1:
    Error varies for each point, but the error values are symmetric (i.e. the
    lower and upper values are equal).

2 x N:
    Error varies for each point, and the lower and upper limits (in that order)
    are different (asymmetric case)

In addition, this example demonstrates how to use log scale with errorbar.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example data
x = np.arange(0.1, 4, 0.5)
y = np.exp(-x)
# example error bar values that vary with x-position
error = 0.1 + 0.2 * x
# error bar values w/ different -/+ errors
lower_error = 0.4 * error
upper_error = error
asymmetric_error = [lower_error, upper_error]

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
ax0.errorbar(x, y, yerr=error, fmt='-o')
ax0.set_title('variable, symmetric error')

ax1.errorbar(x, y, xerr=asymmetric_error, fmt='o')
ax1.set_title('variable, asymmetric error')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Which plots this:

[image]

Comment: It's great.. however I am not getting the '-' at the end of the deviation :-(  (May be some versioning issue)

Comment: @Andi_R's comment on the accepted answer explains how to add the '-'

Here is a copy:


To add those small horizontal lines on the top and the bottom of a candle, specify the capsize option. E.g. to plt.errorbar(x, y, e, linestyle='None', marker='^', capsize=3)