# Plot mean and standard deviation on matplotlib 2.1.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I need plot a function with dots and the standard deviation. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481854/plot-mean-and-standard-deviation?answertab=active#tab-top) has all I need, but I am using matplotlib 2.1.0 on Python 3.4.3 and it doesn't draw upper and lower lines of standard deviation. I mean standard deviation lines doesn't have horizontal lines in their extremes. Is there any way to draw those lines in the matplotlib version which I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust `capsize=` and `capthick=` arguments to the function [`errorbar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar)