# How to rotate the matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new in python and I am using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481854/plot-mean-and-standard-deviation) to plot the mean and std:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
x = df['index']
y = df['mean']
e = df['std']

plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
plt.errorbar(x, y, e, linestyle='None', marker='^')
plt.xticks(x, rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('test', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('size', fontsize=16)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Now the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481854/plot-mean-and-standard-deviation) givinng me this image:
[image: current format]
I want to rotate the plot 90 degree to be like (the x and y lable is also need to rotate):
[image: desire format]

Comment: It's not straight forward to rotate a plot, but maybe you just want to plot the transposition, i.e. `plt.errorbar(y,x, xerr=e)`?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540449/how-can-i-rotate-a-matplotlib-plot-through-90-degrees) ?

Comment: @Rex5 yes, i saw that and i tried but it didnot work

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just tried your suggestion but it did not work

Comment: Gone through the link you mentioned but what do you mean by rotate. I mean what do you want or can you edit that image on that page and paste your requirement. Like you want your y-axis to be at the x-axis and x-axis to be at negative y-axis ?

Comment: "but it didnot work" is not a propper problem description. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Bilgin saying "it did not work" doesn't help much, you need to be more specific about what you're actually after.  as the other comments suggest, your question as stated is very ambiguous

Comment: Update the problem you encountered after trying @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's solution in the question itself.

Comment: @ I updated the question. The second figure is what I want. Sorry, I do know how to reduce the size in the post. It shows really bigger in size.

Comment: So you want to rotate the complete graphics? That would usually better be done externally, like [rotate-images-from-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591733/rotate-images-from-terminal) or [Command line: How do you rotate a PDF file 90 degrees?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394065/command-line-how-do-you-rotate-a-pdf-file-90-degrees)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest so, how about the y axis values. If I do externally, they will be hard to visualize i guess.

Comment: A way could be to save image in a folder, read it and rotate it with https://pythontic.com/image-processing/pillow/rotate

Comment: You can rotate the y axis labels by 180 degrees prior to saving. But then one might ask why not use the transposition as in the first comment?